# why threadpool implementation is slower than normal threads

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I have a code block

```
for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{

      do job;

}
```

initially this job task was executed sequentially (as shown above) but later I made multithreaded with normal threads (inner runnable class implementation) like,

```
for (i=0;i<size;i++)

{
   new threadingclass(some args) 
}

runnable threadingclass  {

  pub void run () {

      do job;

 }
}
```

this worked fine with some thread limit (till system resources were enough) so to avoid resource overloading I implemented same code with standard theadpool implementation (threadpool,executor service and worker thread implementation)

```
threadexecutor t=new threadexecutor(size)

for (i=0 ; i<size ; i++)

{
   t.execute(new threadingclass(some args))
}

runnable threadingclass  {

  pub void run () {

      do job;

  }
}
```

now scenario was like,

I wanted to run loop for 25 times (no. of threads), I tried with all 3 implementations

1. sequential : takes 7 min approx
2. normal multithreading : 40 sec
3. multithreading with threadpool (size : 100) : 2 min approx

I am bit confused why normal threading and thredpool implementation timings differ so much and internally also threadpool does not involve much complex logic.
any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Threadpool overhead is very, very small.  It seems likely there is a problem in your implementation, but without code can only guess.

Comment: You should try to profile the JVM while running your code and see where it spends all that time. Use the `-Xprof` option for the built-in profiler.

Comment: What is `threadexecutor`? Did you try using the JVM-Classes instead of your own?

Comment: Does this mean that you created 25 manual threads, but 100 in the Thread Pool? 100 Threads is quite a lot (unless you have 64 core machine....). Try using `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` threads. Also: What kind of Executor did you create?

Comment: @user3109924 : its not my own implementation , its a standard implemenation available everywhere recomnended and tested by many people

Comment: @Marco13 : actually I wanted to create only 25 threads my normal threading code is doing that but threadpool max size is 100 but it is also creating 25 threads (I have given max limit as 100 just to see performance)

Comment: And did all those people everywhere discover execution took 3 times longer when they tested it?  Seems strange they would recommend if so.  Maybe time to look at the bits unique to your program?  That is where i would start at least.

Comment: So can you show us the real code you executed and not just pseudo code? So we can try it ourselves and see what is wrong.

Comment: Especially, provide a link/information on the 'standard thread pool implementation' that you mentioned. (In fact, there is only ONE **standard** thread pool, namely that in the JDK, in form of the ExecutorServices, but it seems you are not talking about that one...)

Comment: If I take your pseudo code as it is, your second example doesn’t start any threads. Obviously, creating some `Runnable`s without actually run them is the fastest method. Otherwise you have to tell how you implement waiting for them to finish and your time measurement before making any claim about their performance.

Answer (score 1):

It mostly depends on which `ExecutorService` you chose. Here it seems you chose a `FixedThreadPool`, which is basically equivalent to launching your threads in parallel if its size is big enough to hold all the threads. You might even get some performance improvement since threads are not creating on the fly.

`ExecutorService` is usually the way to go since it is readable, maintainable and has almost no overhead. It has also been heavily tested over the past years.

Your results clearly reveal an implementation problem: you probably ran your tests with `size = 100` for the `ExecutorService` example and with `size = 25` for the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Your processor most likely only has 4 or 8 cores. Every thread after that many is actually slowing your system down as it has to keep interrupting a running thread in order to give the next one some time.

Run the thread pool with 4 threads and the manual threads with 4 threads and you will see very little difference in performance.

`ThreadPool` sizes can be configured, as can the number of threads you spawn... set them both to the same number for a valid test.

Comment: It seems running the 25 jobs in separate threads would have precisely the same problem, though.

Comment: @Dolda2000 but 25 is a lot fewer than 100.

Comment: Yes I have servers with 8 cores and 24 GB RAM. actually I have to run this implementation against thread size ~(100-200) so 3-4 threads anyhow will not useful

Comment: Sure, but those extra 75 threads should just by lying idle, not disturbing anything anyway.

Comment: @Dolda Maybe. Maybe not. We can't see enough of the code to be sure.

Comment: @Nachiket then you need a bigger server. A server can run 1 thread per core (2 per core with hyperthreading). That's it. A few more threads than that is fine as threads tend to idle occasionally but no matter how many threads you start up you can only run one per core at any one time.

Comment: @Dolda2000 I accept your point is valid though. Idle threads shouldn't be an issue, assuming they are idle.

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong but honestly I have monitored my system while running this code and I have observed that out of 8 cores at the most 4-5 cores are getting used everytime (I carried out this test 10 times atleast to make sure)

Comment: You are doing something wrong then. Sorry I can't be more detailed than that but if you spin up 1 thread per processor and then have it working hard you will see every core max unless there is something in your OS that is limiting resources allocated to that application.

Comment: @Nachiket: That indicates that you're doing something weird. You should post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem, and we can debug it further.